# Is cwallet.sso really necessary in a Jdeveloper application?

Tags: security, credentials, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

In Jdeveloper, what happen if I remove cwallet.sso? what is this for?

I read that it stores security credentials, but I removed it and my secure pages still asked me to login and I was able to log in using the users that I have in jazn-data.xml and the users that I have in my weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

It's not used for that, and if you are defining the database connection on weblogic server you should not need it, but in development time when you define database connection, or any connection that has password for that matter the cwallet.sso is the one that save and hash this password so that when you copy the project to another person it still works fine.